# How to make entire Gridview Row clickable and open a new link?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

How to make an entire gridview row clickable in ASP.NET?

**This is what I am trying at the moment:**

```
  Protected Sub gv_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
      e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location.href='URL.aspx'")
    End If
  End Sub
```

Each row contains multiple template fields so simply adding a hyperlink to the field is not sufficient in this instance.

Comment: How does your code work?

Comment: Not sure if [**this**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/forums/Articles/HyperLinkField-HyperLink-in-ASPNet-GridView-Example.aspx) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Jumpei It doesn't that's why I am asking for help. I know this can be done as I have done it before I just can't remember the correct syntax.

Comment: @equisde Thanks for the suggestion. No unfortunately this will not work. I need the entire row to be a link not just the field/column.

Comment: Don't forget last single-quote.

Comment: @Jumpei well spotted thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to add a hyperlink to a gridview row using .NET and a little javascript magic.

---

**VB**

```
  Protected Sub gv_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gv.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
      Dim QueryString As String = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "QueryString").ToString
      Dim NavigateURL As String = (ResolveUrl("~/URL.aspx?QueryString=" + QueryString))
      e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", String.Format("javascript:window.location='{0}';", NavigateURL))
      e.Row.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer")
    End If
  End Sub
```

---

**C#**

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if ((e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)) {
        string QueryString = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "QueryString").ToString;
        string NavigateURL = ResolveUrl(("~/URL.aspx?QueryString=" + QueryString));
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onClick", string.Format("javascript:window.location=\'{0}\';", NavigateURL));
        e.Row.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
    }
}
```